# An error occured while processing the http request for the webDAV uploads

Tags: ios, app-store

[image: I got this error while uploading the app into Appstore]

I got this error while uploading the app into Appstore.

Comment: same issue, no idea whats going on

Comment: The same thing happened to me (. does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Rebooting the machine did resolve the problems. Reminder to myself: "Reboot tut gut" (as we Germans say)

Answer (score 1):

try application loader instead of Xcode organizer

Comment: This worked but now its stuck in uploaded state forever

Answer (score -1):

please retry. Ire-tried various times and finally able to upload.

Answer (score -1):

Update X-Code to latest version may solve your problem.